# Certbot cron job NoInstallationError()

Tags: nginx, certbot

Until the most recent Certbot update, everything was working fine. The auto-renew mechanism emails me a status report. Now the report is saying:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log 
Cert not yet due for renewal 
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None 
Cert not yet due for renewal 
Could not choose appropriate plugin for updaters: The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration. 
The error was: NoInstallationError()
```

If I run `certbot renew --dry-run` there are no errors, and letsencrypt.log says "no renewal failures".

I've never changed the /etc/cron.d/certbot file - it always worked flawlessly until now. Is this `NoInstallationError()` something I should be concerned about? What nginx plugin is not working?

Here's the certbot cron file:

```
# /etc/cron.d/certbot: crontab entries for the certbot package
#
# Upstream recommends attempting renewal twice a day
#
# Eventually, this will be an opportunity to validate certificates
# haven't been revoked, etc.  Renewal will only occur if expiration
# is within 30 days.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

Comment: Now I'm in a panic. There was another certbot update yesterday and the cron job sent me this last night:  

    `Attempting to renew cert (winecountryswing.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/winecountryswing.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.  
    The error was: NoInstallationError(). Skipping.  
    All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/winecountryswing.com/fullchain.pem (failure)  
    1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)`

Comment: If I were to guess, it would be that when the cron runs, the nginx binary cannot be found in whatever shell cron is running in. Make sure that it is accessible from your cron shell